# Pass date variable to date parameter for scribe data migration job in powershell

Tags: powershell, data-migration, scribe-workbench

I have the following `powershell` script that passes the `$dateMinusThirty` variable as parameter into `scribe` data migration job:

```
$dateMinusThirty = Get-Date (Get-Date).AddDays(-30).ToString('s') -Format d; 

.\TWorkbench.exe "D:\filePath.dts" /VCreatedBefore="DATEVALUE($dateMinusThirty)" /RS
```

The date is how I need it, Scribe opens, but **immediately crashes**

Am I doing this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is the following:

```
$dateMinusThirty = Get-Date (Get-Date).AddDays(-30).ToString('s') -Format d; 

.\TWorkbench.exe "D:\filePath.dts" /VCreatedBefore="DATEVALUE(\""$dateMinusThirty\"")" /RS
```